# How can I find all ReadGeo nodes in a Nuke script?

Tags: python, nuke

I'm trying to write code to find all "ReadGeo" nodes and find its file path.

Right now my code opens my script and looks for "ReadGeo" nodes, but any ReadGeo nodes created in Nuke manually aren't found.

But, ReadGeo nodes created with code are found

```
def copyreadgeo(projid,scriptid):
    nuke.scriptOpen(farmbarn + '/' + projid + '/' + scriptid)
    #nuke.createNode("ReadGeo")
    for node in nuke.allNodes(recurseGroups=True):
        if node.Class() == "ReadGeo":
            print node.fullName(), ':', node['file'].value()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**: August 30, 2020.

In The Foundry NUKE 12.2v2 `ReadGeo` nodes is a **`ReadGeo2`** class.

[image]

Here's a working code:

```
import nuke

for node in nuke.allNodes():
    if node.Class() == "ReadGeo2":
        node.setSelected(True)

print(nuke.selectedNodes())
```

[image]

Comment: Even better would be to use the shorter version:
`nuke.allNodes("ReadGeo2")`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the class for read geo has been updated to ReadGeo2 or something? That's not uncommon for nuke nodes, the old class would still be available for backwards compatibility